# InferType of Yup schema marks notrequired into required - Typescript

Tags: typescript, yup, inferred-type

I've been trying to create a type out of simple Yup schema but it turns out that properties of inner objects which are marked notRequired become required and I don't understand why.

See sample below, why is platform not valid as it requires a taxonomy property. There were issues with this in the past (2020) but this seems to be solved and I'm using the latest versions.

```
import * as yup from 'yup';
import { object, InferType } from 'yup';

const taxonomySchema = object({
  code: yup.string().required(),
});

const platformSchema = object({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  taxonomy: taxonomySchema.notRequired(),
});

type Platform = InferType<typeof platformSchema>;

const platform: Platform = {
  name: 'Foo',
};
```

```
import * as yup from 'yup';
import { object, InferType } from 'yup';

const taxonomySchema = object().shape({
  code: yup.string().required(),
});

const platformSchema = object({
  name: yup.string().required(),
  taxonomy: taxonomySchema.optional(),
});

type Platform = InferType<typeof platformSchema>;

const platform: Platform = {
  name: 'Blaat',
  taxonomy: undefined,
};

console.log(platform);
```

Comment: You need to make `taxonomy` optional as you are not using it in `platform` object

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tested this but it still requires to define the property taxonomy as far as I can see. Added updated code sample in original post